# Using variable i of for-loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

What I want to do is save variable, repeatedly, but with another number.

I want to save arrays like below.

```
test_1 = 1
test_2 = 1
test_3 = 1
test_4 = 1
test_5 = 1
```

This is what I tried to do.

```
for i in range(1,6):
    test_i = 1
```

But the result was that the number 1 is saved in variable named as "test_i". It seems like change of i doesn't work at variable.

Comment: Don't so this. Use a *container*, like a `list` or a `dict`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is reinitializing the variable `test_i` as 1.

I'm not sure you can do what you wanted to do, maybe you could look into namespaces.